# php generate list from mysql with ids

Tags: php, arrays, list, foreach

I'm trying to generate a list of articles from the this array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [title] => Article1  ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [title] => article2  ) )
```

Also add id value for each article, this is what I have tried, but its not working right.

```
    <ul>

<?php 

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $item) { ?>
    <li id=<?php echo "$id"; ?>> <?php echo "$item"; ?></li>
    <?php  
    }
}


?>  
    </ul>
```

Your helps is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not just change the `$key => $value` in the first foreach so that it becomes:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($result as $item){ ?>
<li id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>>
<?php echo $item['title']; ?>
</li> 
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're close. `$item` is an associative array.You just need to access its values using the proper keys:

```
  <ul>

<?php 

foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $item) { ?>
    <li id="<?php echo $item['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $item['value']; ?></li>
    <?php  
    }
}


?>  
    </ul>
```

Comment: I think $value is the associative array.

Comment: That's a numerical array containing the associative arrays.

Comment: No, that's $result. $key is 0 and 1 and $value is the associative array containing "id" and "title".

Comment: why to get `$key`, as not required/used here

Comment: @MMK In thi scase you would not need to get $key